# Como retornar o último registro de um array com Javascript ou jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Estou fazendo um filtro de pesquisa personalizado onde o usuário pode selecionar a marca e as características do produto e eu retorno o id deles.

Mas eu queria retornar apenas o último registro dos meus *arrays* onde eles contém todas as informações que preciso.

**Eu preciso apenas retornar o último registro apresentado no console como na imagem abaixo. Ex: marca=25,30,53 e caracteristica:10:35:4**

Segue o código:

```
<a href="#" class="filter-link">
  <div class="label_check">
       <input type="checkbox" id="marca-4" class="filter-check" data-tipo="marca?4" value="4">
       <div class="filter-pretty-check"></div>
       <span class="filter-desc">Nokia</span>
  </div>
</a>

    $('#filtrar-opcoes').on('click',function(){                    
                var tipos = [];
                var caracteristicas = [];
                $.each(($("input[type=checkbox]:checked")),function(index, obj){                                                
                    var $tipo =  $(obj).attr('data-tipo');                                                                                   
                    if($tipo.split('?')[0] == 'marca'){
                        tipos.push($tipo.split('?')[1]);                                    
                        var firstPartUrl = $tipo.split('?')[0] + '=' + tipos.join();                                                                
                        console.log(firstPartUrl);                                                                                                                    
                    }
                    if($tipo.split('?')[0] == 'caracteristica'){
                        caracteristicas.push($tipo.split('?')[1]);                            
                        var lastPartUrl = $tipo.split('?')[0] + '=' + caracteristicas.join(':');
                        console.log(lastPartUrl);                            
                    }
                });
            });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito confuso esse seu código. Poderia postar a estrutura html ? Principalmente com os atributos `data-tipo` ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown já adicionei um pedaço da estrutura html

Comment: @GabrielSchmidtCordeiro as duas respostas abaixo não funcionam pra ti?

Comment: @JéfersonBueno não cara. Eu preciso apenas retornar o último registro apresentado no console como na imagem acima. Ex: marca=25,30,53 e caracteristica:10:35:4

Comment: Então edite sua questão e explique qual o seu problema e o que está tentando fazer. Se você ler o título da sua questão vai ver que as duas respostas fazem exatamente o que é dito ali.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando javascript puro, desta forma:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var ultimo = array[array.length - 1];
document.write(ultimo);
```

Ou usar o método at():

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var ultimo = array.at(-1);
document.write(ultimo);
```

Se preferir usar jQuery, você pode fazer algo como:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var ultimo = $(array).get(-1);
document.write(ultimo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Prefiro sua resposta. Assim você não remove o último elemento do `array` caso queria reutilizá-lo em outra coisa. +1

Answer (score 9):

Outra maneira de obter o último elemento do *array*, considerando que ela não remove o último elemento do *array*, seria utilizando a função `slice` apontando para o último elemento através do `-1`.

```js
a = [1, 2, 3]
document.write(a.slice(-1)[0])
```

`slice` retornará o último elemento do *array* dentro de um *array*. Por isso utilizamos o índice `0`.

Veja:

```
a.slice(-1); // Imprime: [3]
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Se não fosse recomendável, eu não estaria postando aqui :). É uma solução e pronto!

Answer (score 5):

Outra maneira também seria usando a função `pop`. Ela remove o ultimo elemento do vetor e o retorna. Não sei se seria recomendável no seu caso.

Veja funcionando aqui.

```js
var vetor1 = new Array(1, 2, 3, 2, 7);
var ultimo = vetor1.pop();
document.write(ultimo);
```

Comment: Lembrando que `pop` remove o último elemento do `array`, e isso não é bom caso ele queria reutilizar o `array`.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim coloquei na resposta como outra maneira e o funcionamento do pop.

Comment: Talvez seja só copiar o `array` antes :)

Answer (score 3):

Se for algo recorrente no projeto, você pode estender o Array implementando um método para isso:

```
Array.prototype.get = function(index) {
    return this[index < 0 ? this.length + index : index];
};
```

Assim, em qualquer lugar, para buscar o último elemento bastaria fazer:

```
arr.get(-1)
```

Ela aplica a mesma lógica descrita na resposta do [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87418/5878), mas de uma maneira *global*, não precisando repetir o código sempre que for acessar o último elemento.

Veja funcionando:

```js
Array.prototype.get = function(index) {
    return this[index < 0 ? this.length + index : index];
};

Array.prototype.last = function(index) {
    return this.get(-1);
};

Array.prototype.first = function(index) {
    return this[0];
};

const arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log('Último elemento com get:', arr.get(-1));
console.log('Último elemento com last:', arr.last());
console.log('Primeiro elemento com first:', arr.first());
```

Comment: Dei o -1, mas acho importante justificar. Embora seja compreensível, por facilidade estender os objetos nativos, essa já é uma prática há tempos considerada _perigosa_ pela comunidade. Todavia, se ainda sim for desejável prosseguir com essa prática, utilizar `Object.defineProperty` é ideal para definir o atributo `[[Enumerable]]` como `false`, evitando comportamentos inesperados em construções como `for..in`.

Comment: @LuizFelipe De fato, concordo contigo e na época (2018) eu não tinha ciência disso xD (infelizmente não tenho tempo agora para atualizar a resposta) :(

Answer (score -3):

Olá!

Consegui fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
//Coloque a última fruta da array em uma variável, sem remover a mesma do array

var frutas = ['Banana','Maçã','Pera','Uva','Melancia']

//Varredura para achar o último item do array (frutas.length - 1)

for (var item = 0; item < frutas.length; item++) {
    if (frutas[item] === frutas[frutas.length - 1]) {
        var ultimaFruta = frutas[item]
        console.log(ultimaFruta)
    }
}
```