# Pegar ultimo objeto do array

Tags: javascript

Como posso pegar sempre o ultimo objeto da array no momento estou usando a seguinte função mas só pega a primeira.

```
var IDs = arrayIds[0].id;

[
  {
    id: '1',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
  }
]
```

Comment: myArray[myArray.length - 1];

Comment: 1. [`array[array.length - 1]`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87418/3635) / 2. [`a.slice(-1)[0]`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87428/3635) / 3. [`array.pop()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87420/3635)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes buscar pelo comprimento usando `.length` menos 1 que sempre retornrá o ultimo item

```js
let arr = [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']


console.log(arr[arr.length -1])
```